# How to know why docker container was restared

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

After auto restart my docker container docker logs <container> shows logs only from start new container. How to know why my container was restared?

docker logs <container>
Also I check logs within container, but nothing found

Comment: #1 You said "auto restart" and then "why my container was restarted". This makes sense?  #2 Also fix the title: is restar**t**ed. #2 Share us the Dockerfile. #3 For this cases I have a snippet called "zombi_mode" who allow me to enter the damaged container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use docker events.

Some examples:

*Get latest 10 minutes events*

```
 docker events --since '10m'
```

*Get events for specific container:*

```
 docker events -f 'container=id'
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/